# How can I generate a signal and sample it simultaneously in STM32F407?

Tags: embedded

I was able to generate a signal using DAC periphery and a HAL_DELAY.
I want to sample this signal using ADC by connecting DAC output to ADC input for FIR filter purposes.
But there is a logical problem, because the code is sequential after generating DAC commands value I can sample with ADC commands but there will be only one DAC value to sample.

Is there a way to simultaneously generate signal with DAC and simultaneously sample it with ADC in STM32F407?

Comment: Are you using DMA?

Comment: No i am not using DMA I am manualy creating the DAC values.
Is there a method to accomplish simultanios generation and sampling of a signal?
Thanks.

Comment: You can find examples of continuous FIR filtering using the CMSIS functions. You may have to ping-pong two ADC buffers rather than using circular buffers directly.

Comment: Hello Spehro,Could you please elaborate more on the PING PONG method on ADC's so i could imagine the proccess?
Thanks.

Comment: Use that as a search term along with CMSIS and Cortex-M4. I'm actually working on something similar as a project but don't have anything to share atm.

Comment: Hello Spero,COuld you please show the intuition of the method you suggest?
How it allows simultanios generating of signal in DAC and sampling it with ADC simultaniosly?
Thanks.

Comment: ADC(DMA)->buffer1/2->(callback) FIR processing->buffer->DAC(DMA)

Comment: Hello Spehro,what is (callback) FIR processing?
i tried to google it but no result for begginers.
Could you help with some method material for begginers

Comment: Try Phil's Lab on Youtube.